# Distinguish between Spectral Emissive power and Spectral Energy Density

Tags: thermal-radiation

Can you distinguish between the two terms(w.r.t) black body-

1. Spectral emissive power
2. Spectral energy density

What i know or believe is that the 1) i.e spectral emissive power is energy radiating per unit area per unit time per unit wavelength for a particular wavelength range.
I dont know what 2) is..
In my notes i have defined it same as 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the dimension you gave, it follows that “Spectral emissive power” is a short designation for “**spectral energy flux density**” - what energy flows through a unit cross section per unit time per unit wavelength (or frequency).

The second quantity is simpler (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/energy-spectral-density) - this is the **spectral energy density** - what energy is per unit wavelength (or frequency). To obtain it, it is necessary to integrate the spectral energy flux density over area and over time. For example, using a set of color filters and a bolometer, you can measure the total energy coming from a light bulb to an illuminated surface of a given area for a given time in a given color range. Dividing this energy by the length of the range, we get “Spectral energy density”, and then dividing by the area and time, we get “Spectral emissive power”. Instead of a light bulb, you can take a “black body” heated to a certain temperature.